# Found a strange group on my Mac

Tags: macos

When I get information on various items such as System Preferences or a specific utility such as Script Editor, I can see that there is a group user called "wheel" that I can not eliminate.  This user group user has both Read and Write permissions to these applications and when I try to eliminate them (when logged in as an one of the users as Administrator), I get a message that indicates that I do not have sufficient permissions to do so.  I have found this group user on both my desktop and my laptop.  Any ideas.

Comment: It would be good to read http://superuser.com/questions/191955/what-is-the-wheel-user-in-os-x/191969

Answer (score 1):

That's perfectly normal. The wheel group is a default group and basically means the group of people who are allowed to use `sudo` or `su` to become root.